# PHP API scripts extremely slow

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 with an nginx webserver installed. I'm writing a mini-social network for the users on my website, but for some reason the scripts I use to load things like profiles and "walls" are sometimes slow. Not all of them are slow, but especially the newsfeed script where it shows recent posts by friends.

I've added a bunch of `microtime()` checks throughout the script and it seems the query to get the recent posts is taking the most time. I tried to optimize it as much as possible but it still seems to be slow. I'm using MySQLi. Here is my query:

```
SELECT `id`,`posterName`, `posterUUID`, `message`, `postDate`, `likes`, `whoLiked`
FROM `wallposts` 
WHERE (
  `wallUUID` IN (' . implode(',', $friendStr) . ') 
   AND posterUUID = wallUUID
)
OR wallUUID="GLOBAL"
AND isDeleted=0
ORDER BY `postDate` DESC
LIMIT 25
```

Would it be faster to just use `SELECT *` since I'm pretty much selecting most of the columns anyway? I'm not sure what else to try, so that's why I came here.

Any help please as to what I could do/not do to keep it from taking 5+ seconds just for this query?

Comment: Do an EXPLAIN on the query to see what indexes its using and how MySQL is executing it

Comment: You say you're using prepared statements: `WHERE (wallUUID IN (' . implode(',', $friendStr) . ')` doesn't look very prepared

Comment: My bad, I usually use prepared statements but for this one I haven't since I was using IN and I was in a hurry. It's not really relevant to the actually issue though... and anyway, I'll try the EXPLAIN thing.

Comment: I ran the query in adminer and got this: http://i.imgur.com/azZYdvz.png

Comment: must be an index problem, check your table and apply appropriate index on fields.

Comment: you are mixing AND and OR in your query

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

- using `*` instead of a list of columns is usually a bad idea, the risk is to add a column that you do not need and this column could be containing large amounts of binary data, this would make your query slower. So it's certainly not something to care about when you have speed problems.
- you may have some priority of logical operators AND/OR problems

Your query is:

```
WHERE (A)
OR B
AND C
```

And I'm pretty sure you mean:

```
WHERE (
  (A)
  OR B
)
AND C
```

But AND takes precedence, so what you have is:

```
WHERE (A)
OR ( 
  B
  AND C
)
```

When in doubt use parenthesis (I'm in doubt there, but I would use parenthesis).

- Your first `WHERE` condition is quite strange:

  WHERE (
    `wallUUID` IN (42,43,44,45,46) 
     AND posterUUID = wallUUID
  )

That mean a filter on the friends identifiers for the wall posts, I guess, and then a filter which says for each row we need to have the same id for the poster uid and for the wall id.

I'm pretty that's not what you wanted. Maybe you need a join query here. Or maybe not, without the structure of your tables it's hard to guess

- You will need a pretty decent indexation to get an optimized result on friend's posts results, an dindex which starts by the current user id, contain sthe right sort by date, the deletion thing, and certainly the friends identifiers.
- user-friends relationships are hard to manage, especially when volumes gets bigger, usually building a social website involves pub/sub systems (publication subscriptions channels systems). You should study some pubsub databases schemas.

Comment: the posterUUID = wallUUID is meant so that we only get results that were posted by the owner of the wall, not friends posting on his/her wall. This is for a 'newsfeed' type of thing. I'm selecting posts from the table where the wallUUID is in the list of the user's friends and it was posted ON the wall BY the owner of that wall, not one of the owner's friends.

Comment: Sorry if it's confusing. The current query returns the proper data, but it's just slow. Thanks for all your info btw, it's really useful and I'll look into some stuff you mentioned.